# Dynamic Types with MongoDB Driver 2.2 - How to not serialize the _t type Discriminator?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have two .Net (C#) applications that are passing "messages" via Mongo.  One is a *Writer*, the other a *Reader*.  The **_t** type discriminator is causing me issues with deserialization.

This is as simplified version of the common class they are using to communicate with:

```
public class MyMessage {
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public string MessageText {get; set;}
    public dynamic OriginalObject{get; set;}
}
```

The *Writer* app is actually creating instances of *MyMessage* by mapping over values from some other type that will be unknown to the *Reader* app.  It maps out the known common elements, and then assigns the entire original object to the dynamic *OriginalObject* property.

```
public MyMessage CreateMessage(SomeOtherType originalMsg) {
    return new MyMessage {
        MessageText = originalMsg.SomeField,
        OriginalObject = originalMsg            
    };
}
```

When the .Net Mongo Driver serializes *MyMessage*, it adds the **_t** type discriminator to the *OriginalObject* sub document.

However, the *Reader* app does not have reference to all of the types that *Writer* does.  When the *Reader* application attempts to deserialize *MyMessage*, it throws an `Unknown discriminator value` error whenever *OriginalObject* is a type it doesn't have.

I've read that the **_t** type discriminator is added whenever the actual type doesn't match the nominal type.  And that makes sense in a true polymorphic, strongly typed scenario.  But now that C# has dynamic typing, I would like to use it.

Also, if the instance of *MyMessage.OriginalMessage* is a purely anonymous type, it works perfectly.  No **_t** type discriminator is written.  The *Reader* app happily deserializes it as a dynamic (expando) object and everything works. It's only when the instance of *OriginalMessage* is some strong type that I have this issue.

**How do I tell the Mongo Driver not to add the _t type discriminator for dynamic types?**
I'm also interested in other solutions/work arounds, but simply excluding the **_t** would be my preferred approach.

.Net Framework 4.6.1, MongoDB.Driver 2.2.3

More sample code:

```
public void SaveMessages()
{
    var message1 = new MyMessage { 
        Id=1, 
        MessageText="Anonymous Message", 
        OriginalMessage=new{ Field1 = "f1", Field2 = "f2" }
    };
    _collection.InsertOne(message1);  // no _t since OriginalMessage is purely anonymous

    var message2 = new MyMessage { 
        Id=2, 
        MessageText="Strong Message", 
        OriginalMessage=new SomeOtherType{Prop1="p1", Prop2="p2"}
    };
    _collection.InsertOne(message2); // has _t since SomeOtherType is not "dynamic"
}
```

Comment: did you try "BsonDocument" instead of "dynamic"?

Comment: Changing the MyMessage definition to use a strong type, like BsonDocument, works just fine.  But I really wanted that dynamic experience to decouple it from a specific type (even if that specific type is flexible like Bson/Json/Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Project` to exclude an item while fetching, like this:

```
return await this.GetCollection()
            .Find(filter: new BsonDocument("_id", handle))
            .Project(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Exclude("_t"))
            .FirstAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but here's a convention to disable the writing of discriminators:

```
internal class NoDiscriminatorConvention : ConventionBase, IClassMapConvention
{
    public void Apply(BsonClassMap classMap)
    {
        classMap.SetDiscriminatorIsRequired(false);
    }
}
```

You can register it on your app startup using:

```
ConventionRegistry.Register("No discriminators for message types",
        new ConventionPack { new NoDiscriminatorConvention() },
        type => typeof(MyMessage).IsAssignableFrom(type));
```

In case you're already mapping the `MyMessage` class, e.g. for using the `Id` property as MongoDB's `_id` element, you can do it right there:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyMessage>(cm => {
    cm.MapIdMember(m => m.Id).SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId));
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.SetDiscriminatorIsRequired(false); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution of [mnibic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47135631/1691132) didn't work for me with mongodriver 2.10.

But I was able to use **UndiscriminatedActualTypeSerializer** to prevent _t and _v to be added:

```
public class UndiscriminatedActualTypeConvention : ConventionBase, IClassMapConvention
{
    public void Apply(BsonClassMap cm)
    {
        Type type = cm.ClassType;
        if (type.IsClass
            && type != typeof(string)
            && type != typeof(object)
            && !type.IsAbstract)
        {
            foreach (var memberMap in cm.DeclaredMemberMaps)
            {
                var genericBase = typeof(UndiscriminatedActualTypeSerializer<>);
                var genericType = genericBase.MakeGenericType(new[] { memberMap.MemberType });
                var serializer = genericType
                    .GetProperty("Instance", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static)
                    .GetValue(null, null) as IBsonSerializer;

                cm.MapMember(memberMap.MemberInfo).SetSerializer(serializer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage at the beginning of the program:

```
ConventionRegistry.Register("No discriminators",
    new ConventionPack { new UndiscriminatedActualTypeConvention() },
    type => true);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63686596/1536933 (by **Kevin Smith**) has an answer that worked for me. For anyone finding this question first, the gist of it is:

```
public class NullDiscriminatorConvention : IDiscriminatorConvention
{
    public static NullDiscriminatorConvention Instance { get; }
        = new NullDiscriminatorConvention();

    public Type GetActualType(IBsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType)
        => nominalType;

    public BsonValue GetDiscriminator(Type nominalType, Type actualType)
        => null;

    public string ElementName { get; } = null;
}


BsonSerializer.RegisterDiscriminatorConvention(YourType, NullDiscriminatorConvention.Instance);
```